# scheme determine a string inside a tree list or not

Tags: scheme, racket

Here's my data definition,

```
(define-struct leaf ())

;; interpretation: represents a leaf on a BT, a node with no children

(define-struct node (word left right))

;; interpretation: represents a node on a BT with a word, a left and a right 
;; subtree

;; A BinaryTree (BT) is one of 
;; - (make-leaf)
;; - (make-node String BT BT)

;; bt-has? : BT String -> Boolean
;; given a BT tree and a String w and returns true if w is in the tree 
;; and false otherwise

(define (bt-has? tree w)
(cond 
   [(leaf? tree) (bt-has? tree w)]
   [(and (node? tree)
         (string=? w (node-word (first tree))))
    (bt-has?  (rest tree) w) ]))
```

I don't know why it keeps giving the all question results were false error code.

```
(string=? w (node-word (first tree))))
```

seems right to me. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show how you create the tree you are working with?

Comment: @ScottHunter ;; A BinaryTree (BT) is one of 
;; - (make-leaf)
;; - (make-node String BT BT)

Comment: @ScottHunter I think i identify the problem. Here tree is a structure not a list.

Comment: Are you sure that a `leaf` should not contain a word?

Comment: @benrudgers It was given as a kind of empty state which confuses me at beginning. Yes it does not contain a word. So every time there is a leaf, it must be coped with false.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the mistake i made was BT(tree) is a structure not a list so that's why this error code pops.
Here's a revised version.

```
;; bt-has? : BT String -> Boolean
;; given a BT tree and a String w and returns true if w is in tree 
;; and false otherwise

(define (bt-has? tree w)
   (cond 
      [(leaf? tree) false]
      [else
          (and (node? tree)
               (string=? w (node-word tree))
               (bt-has? (node-left tree) w)
               (bt-has? (node-right tree) w))]))

 ;; tests 

    (check-expect (bt-has?  (make-node "a" (make-leaf) (make-node "b" (make-leaf) (make-leaf) "a")) true)
    (check-expect (bt-has?  (make-node "a" (make-leaf) (make-leaf)) "b")false)
    (check-expect (bt-has?  (make-leaf) "a") false)
```

Comment: Since your new code only checks the root, I'll bet `(bf-has? (make-node "a" (make-node "b" (make-leaf) (make-leaf)) (make-leaf)) "b")` yields `false`.

Comment: @ScottHunter right! need recursion? Any suggestions?

Comment: Your modification is headed in the right direction, but it isn't a valid `cond` entry: you need a boolean expression and the value (in this case, also a boolean) to return if that condition is true, but you have one recursive call for the test and the other for the value to return.

Comment: @ScottHunter what do you mean by that? (string=? w (node-word tree))) determines whether this nord-word is w but i have to figure the situation in bt-left, bt-right.

Comment: In English, (bf-has? tree w) is tree is a node and either w is the word at the root or w is in the left subtree or w is in the right subtree.  Your new code translates to tree is a node *and* w is at the root *and* w is in the left subtree *and* w is in the right subtree.

Comment: The only thing you need to change here is the `and` for an `or` You want to know if `w` is the word of this node `or` the word of any of the 2 sub-trees. Also, there is no need to check if it is a `node` in the else clause. A tree can only be a `leaf` or a `node`, and at that point, we already know it's not a `leaf`.

Comment: Also noticed. In your first test, you have a misplace `)`. It should be after the second `(make-leaf)` of `node b` And leave the `"a"` outside of the `BT`.