# scheme consumes BT tree and returns the elements of the tree as a list of strings

Tags: scheme, racket

You are provided with the following definition for binary tries

```
(define-struct leaf ())
;; interpretation: represents a leaf on a BT, a node with no children

(define-struct node (word left right))
;; interpretation: represents a node on a BT with a word, a left and a right 
;; subtree

;; A BinaryTree (BT) is one of 
;; - (make-leaf)
;; - (make-node String BT BT)
```

Design the program bt->los that consumes a BT tree and returns the elements of the tree as a list of strings. At each node your function should

1.process the left sub tree

2.process the word at this node

3.process the right sub tree

```
;; bt->los: tree -> los 
;; consumes a BT tree and returns the elements of the tree as a list of strings.
(define (bt->los tree)
(cond 
   [(leaf? tree) ""]
   [(node? tree) 
    (append  (bt->los(list (node-left tree)))
             (list (node-word tree))
             (bt->los (list (node-right tree))))]))
```

I'm stuck here. Should have missed something. Don't we need recursion here?

Output should be like,

```
 (define bt-abc (make-node "b" 
                       (make-node "a" (make-leaf) (make-leaf))
                       (make-node "c" (make-leaf) (make-leaf))))
  (bt->los bt-abc) (cons "a" (cons "b" (cons "c" empty)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close here. Just a couple of mistakes.

```
(define (bt->los tree)
 (cond 
   [(leaf? tree) empty]
   [(node? tree) 
    (append  (bt->los (node-left tree))
             (list (node-word tree))
             (bt->los (node-right tree)))]))
```

First, you are constructing a list of string. Because it is a list, your base case should be `empty`. not `""`. Second, each node, already represents a BT, there is no need to `list` it. And `bt->los` returns 
a list. With this simple changes, it works as expected for you test case.

Comment: can you take a look this question as well? thanks!!!   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662745/scheme-determine-a-string-inside-a-tree-list-or-not/26663101?noredirect=1#comment41932726_26663101